# Azure Devops release - File Transform - Provided node is empty or a comment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to transform a .config file from an XML transform file in a release stage.  I am using the standard File Transform task.  I added a transform.xml file (which isnt linked to a legitimate release) to my artifact and can see it.  When i try and use it I get the following System.Debug output:

```
2020-05-01T17:25:21.6011428Z Processing substitution for xml node : connectionStrings
2020-05-01T17:25:21.6022113Z ##[debug]Provided node is empty or a comment.
2020-05-01T17:25:21.6025339Z ##[debug]Provided node is empty or a comment.
2020-05-01T17:25:21.6027416Z ##[debug]Unable to find node with tag 'configSections' in provided xml file.
2020-05-01T17:25:21.6028615Z Skipped Updating file: xxxxxxxx.config
```

The contents of the transform.xml file are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="XX" connectionString="user id=XXX;password=XXXXX;data source=XXXXXXXX"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops release - File Transform - Provided node is empty or a comment

I could not reproduce this issue with following configuration file and your transform file:

Configuration file **web.config** (code sample from [XML transformation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSDB;DbFilename=aspcore-local.mdf;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then create a **Web.test.config** with your contents of the transform file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <connectionStrings xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add name="XX" connectionString="user id=XXX;password=XXXXX;data source=XXXXXXXX"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

**Note:**

XML transformation will be run on the ***.config** file for transformation configuration files named `*.Release.config` or `*.<stage>.config`. So, we could not use the `transform.xml` instead of `*.<stage>.config`.

As the test result, the `connectionStrings` string in the `web.config` was replaced:

[image]

Please check the document [File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am putting the following in the Transformation Rules section of the file transform task `-transform **\*Transform.config -xml **\*.config` I assumed the transform file could be named anything?  Otherwise why is the parameter in the rules there...?

Comment: @DominicCotton, Yes,  the transform file could be named anything. But you need to make sure you have that file in your artifact with name **\*Transform.config**. I test it also works fine, would you mind share your web.config to me, so that I could test it, or you could test it with my web.config to check if you still have this issue?